# Custom Route is not called for ASP.NET MVC 3 application .NET 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I've tried to create custom route for *.ogg file which is played in website with HTML 5 audio tag.

The fact is that FireFox doesn't play ogg if we don't provide application/ogg as ContentType.
Unlike Chrome plays ogg without extra work.

By the way, I think custom route and register it in Global.asax is a good solution and reusable code.
For every path with .ogg extension, server sends ogg file with application/ogg ContentType.

The problem is that I don't know why path with *.ogg is not processed with custom route.

This is my code for OggHandler.cs

```
 public class OggHandler : IRouteHandler, IHttpHandler
{

    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        return this;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// process ogg file
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var request = context.Request;
        var response = context.Response;


        try
        {
            //response ogg file with Content Type Header
            response.ContentType = "application/ogg";
            response.WriteFile(request.PhysicalPath);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            response.Write("<html>\r\n");
            response.Write("<head><title>Ogg HTTP Handler</title></head>\r\n");
            response.Write("<body>\r\n");
            response.Write("<h1>" + ex.Message + "</h1>\r\n");
            response.Write("</body>\r\n");
            response.Write("</html>");
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }




}
```

and the registration in Global.asax

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.Add(new Route
                       (
                       "{resource}.ogg/{*pathInfo}"
                       , new OggHandler()
                       ));



        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

    }
```

Hope to get good suggestion from you all. :)

Lately, I also attached simple project file as the following link.

http://codesanook.com/shared/MvcOgg.zip

Comment: You get this problem in IIS or Visual Studio Web Server ?

Comment: IIS Development Server built-in server with VS 2010

Comment: what exactly doesn't work? You get a 404?

Comment: OggHandler is not called and not return *.ogg file with application/ogg content-type.
I don't get 404 file not found.

Comment: Note that route registration order is important. Are you registering any other routes before, or even resetting the routes collection?

Comment: I've edit original post to show full route registration or you may download attached project to test it.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first: have you checked it doesn't work if you specify the additional  application/ogg mimetype mapped to .ogg files either in IIS or web.config web server section?

Then, I think the problem is that your route registration will only match single segment URL (/filename.ogg) . You should specify your route pattern as {*musicpath}/.ogg

Third thing, more stylistic than other, you should make a oggroutehandler class that crates the ogghttphandler. This way you keep separation of the two competences.

Sorry I couldn't check it better but I'm on a smartphone :)
HTH

Simone

Comment: Hi Simone,thank you very much for useful advice.
Because I don't have authorization to config IIS and that I can do is coding in app. 
However, I haven't make it done. I would be appriciate if you could check my attached project http://codesanook.com/shared/MvcOgg.zip and help me to fix it out. :)